# Ruby regex to match content between <ul> tags

Tags: html, ruby, regex

I have a script to grab a page and edit it. The page HTML looks something like this:

```
<p>Title</p>...extra content...<ul><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li></ul>
```

There are multiple titles and multiple unordered lists but I want to change each list with a regular expression that can find the list with a certain title and use .sub in Ruby to replace it.

The regex I currently have looks like this:

```
regex = /<p>Title1?.*<\/ul>/
```

Now if there are any items below the regex it will match to the last tag and accidentally grab all the lists below it for example if I have this content:

```
content = "<p>Title1</p><ul><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li></ul><p>Title2</p><ul><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li><li>Item3</li></ul>"
```

and I want to add another list item to the section for Title 1:

```
content.sub(regex, "<p>Title1</p><ul><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li><li>NEW_ITEM</li></ul>)
```

It will delete all items below it. How do I rewrite my regex to select only the first /ul tag to substitute?

Comment: Use an HTML parser insead?

Comment: Use **Non-Grddey(Lazy)** way `<p>Title1?.*?<\/ul>`

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use a non-greedy (lazy) quantifier `.*?`

See this explanation of [Ruby `Regexp` repetition](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Repetition).

```
regex = /<p>Title1?.*?<\/ul>/
```

Answer (score 4):

"I want to change each list with a regular expression." No you don't. You really do not want to go down this road because it's filled with misery, sorrow, and tears. One day someone will put a list item in your list item.

There are libraries like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) that make manipulating HTML very easy. There's no excuse to not use something like it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = "<p>Title</p>...extra content...<ul><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li></ul>"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

doc.css('ul').children.first.inner_html = 'Replaced Text'

puts doc.to_s
```

That serves as a simple example for "replace text from first list item". It can be easily adapted to do other things, as the `css` method takes a simple CSS selector, not unlike jQuery.

Comment: Guess what? I don't care because this isn't a very complex script. I've used nokogiri and it's too much overhead for what this does. Also it reformats the html with newlines and changes all <br /> to <br> which does not go well with the API I am using. So in a nutshell that's why I'm not using it.

Comment: There's other HTML parsing libraries. If you've got something that works for your narrow use case, great, but this is a more general-purpose solution. Nokogiri has options on how much cleanup and rewriting it does, but those are omitted in this simple example.

Comment: Nokogiri isn't nearly as heavy as having your code break just because the HTML format changed. Using regular expressions against HTML that you control isn't as bad/challenging as trying to do it with HTML that can change without warning at someone else's whim.

Comment: They *could* change but they won't this is an internal page that I manage

Answer (score 1):

> ...it reformats the html with newlines and changes all `<br />` to `<br>`...

That's usually because the wrong method is used when emitting the doc as HTML or XHTML:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('<p>foo<br />bar</p>')
doc.to_xhtml # => "<p>foo<br />bar</p>"
doc.to_html # => "<p>foo<br>bar</p>"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('<p>foo<br>bar</p>')
doc.to_xhtml # => "<p>foo<br />bar</p>"
doc.to_html # => "<p>foo<br>bar</p>"
```

As for spuriously adding line-ends where they weren't before, I haven't seen that. It's possible to *tell* Nokogiri to do that if you're modifying the DOM, but from what I've seen, on its own Nokogiri is very benign.